# ActionScript3 | Object or Array

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

What is the difference between - Object and Array? When should I use Array and when to use the Object?

Please give examples - how to use them correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Objects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#Object())

When we talk about an `Object` in ActionScript 3, it is important to note that *everything* inherits `Object` and that a vanilla `Object` instance is `dynamic` (meaning you can freely attach data to it without that data being defined within the class definition).

You are able to initialize a vanilla object using `new Object()` or the `{ }` object literal syntax.

A dynamic object is a `key:value` store, meaning it stores values against strings that can be used to later reference a value. Values can be set or retrieved this way using dot notation (`object.key`) or square bracket notation (`object['key']`). The main difference between the two is that with square bracket notation, you are able to:

- Get or set values with dynamic keys (e.g. after building a string, parsing a file that lists properties, etc.
- Have keys that contain illegal characters like whitespace.

A full example of all of this would be something like:

```
var data:Object = { };

data.firstName = 'John';
data['lastName'] = 'Smith';

trace(data['firstName'] + ' ' + data.lastName); // John Smith
```

The object literal syntax is able to accept `key:value` pairs as well, meaning the above could be simplified to:

```
var data:Object = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith' };
```

Iterating over the `key:value` store of an `Object` is achieved using the `for..in` loop:

```
for(var prop:String in data)
{
    trace(prop, data[prop]);
}
```

## [Arrays](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html)

Note that based on the above, we know that `Array` directly inherits `Object`. The `Array` class is also `dynamic`, which means you are able to use the same `key:value` storage as above with `Object`. This is where it starts getting confusing.

Arrays can be initialized using:

- `new Array()`
- The `[]` array literal syntax.
- The top level [`Array()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#Array()) function.

Arrays are able to store *sequential* data vs an arbitrary collection of values. Although the values we added to the `data` object above appear sequential, they are actually stored in *no particular order*.

Arrays store sequential data using a zero-based numeric index in place of 'keys', something like this:

```
var array:Array = [];
array[0] = 'hello';

trace(array[0]); // hello
```

Arrays provide methods for dealing with adding and removing elements from the head and tail of the array, like `push()`, `pop()`, `shift()` and `unshift()`. Arrays are also able to offer their `length`, representing the number of elements in that array.

The confusion arises when you start using non-numeric keys with an array:

```
array['prop'] = 10;
```

Instead of adding an element to sequential list, we actually go back to the `Object` that the array inherits from an add an arbitrary `prop` key with the value `10`. In this case, we have *one* item *in the array* (the string `hello`), and a dynamic property named `prop` attached to the array instance itself (*not in the array*).

To iterate over an array of items, we can use either a normal `for` loop or the `for each` loop:

```
for(var index:int = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    trace(array[index]);
}

// Or:

for each(var value:String in array)
{
    trace(value);
}
```

It is important to note that the `for each` loop only works if all of your values in the array are of the same type used in the definition for that loop (`String` in this case).

## [Vectors](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html)

Vectors are a specialized sequential data store that allows you to benefit from static type checking by defining what type of objects you will be storing upfront. For example, we can create a list of `Sprite` objects using the following syntax:

```
var sprites:Vector.<Sprite> = new <Sprite>[];
```

Because Vectors are typed, adding a non-Sprite value to the list will give you a compile-time error, saving a lot of potential bugs. Vectors also provide faster read and write access than Arrays.

Comment: "The confusion arises when you start using non-numeric keys with an array:" – would anyone ever intentionally do that? I can think of some hackish uses for it but it is pretty off.

Comment: @TOMATO If you come from a background where arrays work differently (e.g. PHP) you might end up in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Array is used for numerical access, and is zero-based (0 is first element)

```
var array:Array = new Array("a", "b", "c");
array[0] = "z";  // change first element to z
array.push("d"); // add d to end

trace(array[3]) // output: d
trace(array)    // output: z,b,c,d
```

Arrays can be looped through.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
{ 
    trace(array[i]); 
}
```

Object can be used for a variety of things. Compared with Array, it can allow for associative arrays (using strings for keys instead of integers)

```
var assocArray:Object = {me:"Mike", you:"Gabriel"};

// property-style access
trace( assocArray.me ) // output Mike

// access with string
trace( assocArray["you"] ) // Gabriel
```